# "systemctl start pm2-user-name" gives ERROR

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, pm2

I’m setting up a new server and trying now to get pm2 installed and working following this instructions https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04

When trying `sudo systemctl start pm2-userName` I get this error message: "Job for pm2-userName.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration."

Any help would be very much appreciated since I am stuck on this. Thanks!"

I have followed this steps until now:
- `sudo npm install pm2@latest -g` //(installed fine!)
- `pm2 start hello.js` //(working fine!)
- `pm2 startup systemd` //(i get a sudo env PATH... to copyPaste)
- copyPasted `sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u carles --hp /home/carles` //(and everything looks still fine and working (See STARTUP SCRIPT BELOW)
- `sudo pm2 save` (worked)
- s`udo systemctl start pm2-carles` (FAILED! as Job for pm2-carles.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.)
- `systemctl status pm2-carles.service` //(loaded but Active: failed (Result: protocol)

STARTUP SCRIPT/// ##########################

```
[PM2] Init System found: systemd
Platform systemd
Template
[Unit]
Description=PM2 process manager
Documentation=https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=carles
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Environment=PM2_HOME=/home/carles/.pm2
PIDFile=/home/carles/.pm2/pm2.pid
Restart=on-failure

ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect
ExecReload=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 reload all
ExecStop=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Target path
/etc/systemd/system/pm2-carles.service
Command list
[ 'systemctl enable pm2-carles' ]
[PM2] Writing init configuration in /etc/systemd/system/pm2-carles.service
[PM2] Making script booting at startup...
[PM2] [-] Executing: systemctl enable pm2-carles...
[PM2] [v] Command successfully executed.
+---------------------------------------+
[PM2] Freeze a process list on reboot via:
$ pm2 save

[PM2] Remove init script via:
$ pm2 unstartup systemd
```

#

JOURNALCTL -XE ###############################################

````
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 33m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:36:19 future-card pm2[4752]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 33m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4783]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 33m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:36:20 future-card pm2[4815]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 33m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:36:21 future-card pm2[4846]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 47m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5168]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 47m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:50:20 future-card pm2[5200]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 47m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:50:21 future-card pm2[5233]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 47m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:50:22 future-card pm2[5265]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: [PM2] Resurrecting
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: [PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/carles/.pm2/dump.pm2
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: ┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: │ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ c
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: ├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: │ hello    │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ 3268 │ online │ 0       │ 47m    │ 0
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]: └──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──
Jul 09 09:50:23 future-card pm2[5295]:  Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app```

I expect sudo systemctl start pm2-carles to run and work, instead I am getting "pm2-carles.service - PM2 process manager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pm2-carles.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Tue 2019-07-09 09:50:23 UTC; 1min 2s ago
     Docs: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
  Process: 5295 ExecStart=/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)"
````

Answer (score 22):

Rebooting the virtual server worked for me with:

```
sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
ps aux | grep pm2 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

The above kills the pm2 service daemon after which you can restart it with root privileges. (This is if you are running from the directory /usr/bin/pm2).

Got the above from github pm2 thread

Answer (score 17):

We need to kill the existing master process first and restart the pm2 master process with systemd. The following steps will fix your issue.

1. run `pm2 kill` to kill the master process if it launched already.
2. run `pm2 startup systemd`.
3. run the command it generates on step 2

> sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
> startup systemd -u USERNAME --hp /home/USERNAME

4. run `sudo systemctl start pm2-USERNAME`, now you have a pm2 master process managed by systemd.
5. You can verify it with `systemctl status pm2-USERNAME`.
6. run `pm2 save` to save your app configuration to `/home/USERNAME/.pm2`,

so systemd launched pm2 master process can resume it from after a server restart.

You can find more about this issue [here at the github](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3924#issuecomment-714626217)

Comment: this worked on my end. Thank you!